# What is the best module for HttpRequest in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

I wish to use **OCaml** to access the Yahoo Finance API. Essentially, it will be just a bunch of HTTP requests to get quotes from Yahoo Finance.

**Which module I should use?**

I wish to have async HTTP requests.

Comment: Did you consider `Ocamlnet` http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/ocamlnet.html

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not really, I am a total new learner and know nothing. Is Ocamlnet the best?

Comment: I don't know if it is the best, but it is very good.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch does it provide `async ability`?

Comment: I've used to ocamlnet for this exact purpose recently there was no async ability.

Comment: rgrinberg, you are wrong, ocamlnet can issue async requests

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch could you please give me a simple sample code fragment for: loading a url, get the http page string out of it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are possibilities using [lwt](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/manual/):

- [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/ocsigenserver/api/Ocsigen_http_client) has a quite complete and a bit complex implementation
- [cohttp](https://github.com/avsm/ocaml-cohttp/blob/master/lwt/cohttp_lwt_unix.mli) is a bit simpler but lacks some usefull parts

using [opam](http://opam.ocamlpro.com) to install:

```
$ opam install ocsigenserver cohttp
```

For instance in a toplevel:

```
try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH") with _ -> ();;
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#require "ocsigenserver";;
open Lwt

(* a simple function to access the content of the response *)
let content = function
  | { Ocsigen_http_frame.frame_content = Some v } ->
      Ocsigen_stream.string_of_stream 100000 (Ocsigen_stream.get v)
  | _ -> return ""

(* launch both requests in parallel *)
let t = Lwt_list.map_p Ocsigen_http_client.get_url
  [ "http://ocsigen.org/";
    "http://stackoverflow.com/" ]

(* maps the result through the content function *)
let t2 = t >>= Lwt_list.map_p content

(* launch the event loop *)
let result = Lwt_main.run t2
```

and using cohttp:

```
try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH") with _ -> ();;
#use "topfind";;
#require "cohttp.lwt";;
open Lwt

(* a simple function to access the content of the response *)
let content = function
  | Some (_, body) -> Cohttp_lwt_unix.Body.string_of_body body
  | _ -> return ""

(* launch both requests in parallel *)
let t = Lwt_list.map_p Cohttp_lwt_unix.Client.get
  (List.map Uri.of_string
     [ "http://example.org/";
       "http://example2.org/" ])

(* maps the result through the content function *)
let t2 = t >>= Lwt_list.map_p content

(* launch the event loop *)
let v = Lwt_main.run t2
```

Notice that an implementation of cohttp for jane street async library is also available

Comment: The "+../toplevel" is a bit misleading here: this is not necessary for compilers installed by OPAM and it won't work for the system compiler (you should use `try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH") with _ -> ()` instead).

Comment: @Thomas I think your suggestion is very good. And I can't run the codes, but can with your `try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH") with _ -> ()`. Could you please modify his other code?

Comment: @Thomas I am a newbie, could you please tell me what is `Some (_, body)`?

Comment: It's a pattern matching against an optional pair. In this case, the first element of the pair is discarded and the second one is bind to the name "body". Read about "pattern-matching" if you want to know more about that.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your reply. So `Some` is kind of keyword in `pattern-matching`?

Comment: @Thomas what is the meaning of `t >>=` in `let t2 = t >>= Lwt_list.map_p content`?

Comment: @JacksonTale It is some sugar for Lwt.bind. See [Lwt doc](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/api/Lwt#VALbind)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, there is also [ocurl with curl multi API support](http://repo.or.cz/w/ocurl.git).