# "Error: unbound module" in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Here's a simple example of using the library Cohttp:

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix

let body =
  Client.get (Uri.of_string "http://www.reddit.com/") >>= fun (resp, body) ->
  let code = resp |> Response.status |> Code.code_of_status in
  Printf.printf "Response code: %d\n" code;
  Printf.printf "Headers: %s\n" (resp |> Response.headers |> Header.to_string);
  body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string >|= fun body ->
  Printf.printf "Body of length: %d\n" (String.length body);
  body

let () =
  let body = Lwt_main.run body in
  print_endline ("Received body\n" ^ body)
```

I'm trying to compile it

```
 ocaml my_test1.ml
```

Error:

> Error: Unbound module Lwt

**How to actually include/require the module Lwt into my app?**

**update**

Also:

```
$ ocamlbuild
bash: ocamlbuild: command not found
```

But:

```
$ opam install ocamlbuild
[NOTE] Package ocamlbuild is already installed (current version is
       0.12.0).
```

And

```
$ opam install ocamlfind
[NOTE] Package ocamlfind is already installed (current version is
       1.7.3-1).
```

And

```
$ ocamlfind
bash: ocamlfind: command not found
```

Where are ocamlfind and ocamlbuild located?

**update2**

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package lwt -c my_test1.ml 
 File "my_test1.ml", line 2, characters 5-11:
 Error: Unbound module Cohttp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between module and package Ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681939/difference-between-module-and-package-ocaml)

Comment: @coredump it's not

Comment: did you run 'eval $(opam config env)' before running your commands ? (it should solve 'command not found' issues). Regarding lwt and cohttp, you may miss some package on the ocamlbuild commands (-pkg lwt and so on)

Comment: @PierreG., no. Where is it said that I need to run it?

Comment: @PierreG., see my update

Comment: 1st question : generally this is what opam tells after running 'opam switch <compiler_version>' , so not your case.    2nd question : from https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp  : 'ocamlbuild -pkg cohttp-lwt-unix client_example.native'. so I guess 'ocamlfind ocamlc -package cohttp-lwt-unix -c my_test1.ml' might work (... I do not have ocaml environment under my hand currently)

Comment: @PierreG., thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have several options depending on your needs.

1) If you want to create a full project for your binary I recommend looking at [jbuilder](http://jbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here is a very nice guide that explains the environment/project configuration step-by-step: [OCaml for the impatient](https://adambard.com/blog/getting-started-with-ocaml/).

2) Another option is to compile the binary directly as you were trying to do:

```
ocamlbuild -pkg lwt -pkg cohttp-lwt-unix my_test1.native
```

Note that you need to have a file named `my_test1.ml` to generate the requested `my_test1.native`.

3) And finally for quick scripts I find it handy to be able to ask the OCaml interpreter to load the dependencies directly in the source file. Just add the following to the beginning of your file:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "lwt";;
#require "cohttp-lwt-unix";;
```

And then run `ocaml my_test1.ml`.

---

Hope this helps! :)

Also looking at the `command not found` errors you are getting I can suggest to make sure your environment is correctly configured. The Real World OCaml book has a wiki page for that: https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions

Comment: and cohttp_lwt_unix is available thx to 'opam install cohttp-lwt-unix' (underscore '_' of the package name becomes a dash '-').

Comment: i'd run "opam init" before I posted my question

Comment: `opam init` will update your shell profile to include the correct env settings. But the current shell will still have the old environment. So you need to run "eval `opam config env`" to load the environment in the current shell (with backquote around "opam config env").

Comment: 2) Unknown directive `require'.

Comment: `$ opam install topfind` ====> `[ERROR] No package named topfind found.`

Comment: I'm pretty sure your environment is not correctly set up. Do you have an an `~/.ocamlinit` file with the following content? `(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;`

Comment: Run `opam init` and try adding "eval `opam config env`" to your shell's init file (`~/bashrc` if your'e using bash).

Comment: building with dune fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile it like this ...

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -o my_test \ 
   -linkpkg \ 
   -package lwt,cohttp,cohttp-lwt-unix \
   -thread 
    my_test.ml
```