# error when trying to run a file as a script

Tags: ocaml

According to this ["Error: unbound module" in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058993/error-unbound-module-in-ocaml/48065338#48065338)

I should be able to run this

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "lwt";;
#require "cohttp-lwt-unix";;
```

as `ocaml my_test1.ml`

But after I've installed all the libraries and running it as such, I have an error:

```
$ ocaml my_test.ml 
Cannot find file topfind.
Unknown directive `require'.
```

**update**

```
$ ocaml my_test.ml 
File "./my_test.ml", line 1:
Error: Reference to undefined global `Mutex'
```

**update2**

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "lwt";;
#require "cohttp-lwt-unix";;
#thread;;

open Cohttp
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix

let () =
  Printf.printf ("test1")
;;
```

and

```
eval `opam config env`

ocaml test1.ml
```

same error:

```
File "./test1.ml", line 1:
Error: Reference to undefined global `Mutex'
```

Comment: WFM. Likeliest problem is that your environment isn't set up. Does `opam switch` warn you about that?

Comment: @JulianFondren, yes. But still not working. 1) After I've run `  eval `opam config env`  ` and open a new terminal window, the environment gets restored to the previous state and I have to run `   eval `opam config env`  ` again. Why?

Comment: sounds like A) my_test.ml doesn't contain the listed contents, and B) that you're missing a `#thread;;`

Comment: Just a small comment: when you do ``eval `opam config env` ``, it just sets things up in  the shell in that particular window. You need to do it again for each window (or add the initialization to your shell startup files).

Comment: @JulianFondren I've added "#thread;;" but the error remains

Comment: @Loku move the `#thread;;` above the line with the error.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the interpreter is picking the single-threaded runtime. Probably, there is some problem with your installation or it is a bug in ocamlfind. If you're using system OCaml installation, then my suggestion would be to switch to OPAM's compiler, e.g.,

```
opam switch 4.05.0
```

then install the necessary packages, e.g.,

```
opam install cohttp-lwt-unix
```

and do not forget to activate your switch with

```
eval `opam config env`
```

If the problem still persists, then try to install another version of OCamlFind. If you still have a problem, then submit a bug report. The code you're showing should work (and works on mine machine).

Answer (score 1):

`ivg` is right in that the interpreter is picking the single-threaded runtime, but that's something you have to fix in your application by adding `#thread` yourself:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#require "lwt";;
#require "cohttp-lwt-unix";;
```

This is related to some recent changes in `lwt` and `ocamlfind`. You can find some pointers in [this bug report](https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/issues/533) I opened recently.